# .net core wpf app requires Microsoft.AspNetCore.App. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have wpf app that ofcourse has lot of project and nuget dependencies.
But, all of those require `Microsoft.NETCore.App` framework but when I want to install app on some other machine app reports that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` needs to be installed on computer. I don't want use to install anything besides my app.

I know that web apps have dependency on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` but my app don't reference any "web dll"

[image: all libs required only NETCore.App]

Edit:
It seems I shared models between client and server and models dll has dependency on
Microsoft.AspNetCore.ProtectedData
but I still don't know why aspnetcore.app shared lib is needed

Comment: Are you sure that .net core runtime or sdk is installed at the target machine?

Comment: I want all to packaged so user doesn't need to install anything besides app in ideal case. But it confuses me because it requires AspNetCore.App

Comment: I would suggest looking into [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file)

Comment: You will need a self-contained app, instead of a framework dependent - https://andrewlock.net/should-i-use-self-contained-or-framework-dependent-publishing-in-docker-images/ - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained

Comment: I guess a NuGet package will introduce the dependency to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`, but can't say for sure based on your information, btw a wpf app should have the framework `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF` did you specify `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` in your csproj file? https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vnLA.png

Comment: It has UseWPF set to true

Comment: @Rand Random yes, probably microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframework core introduced dependency because I wanted to extend User.class with IdentityUser